# Any way to speed up my queries in MariaDB with tables less than a 4 GB in size?

Tags: performance, mariadb

I'm doing some text mining work and a bit frustrated that queries are taking 6 to 10 minutes to run.

My workstation has a 3.5ghz Xeon, 32GB of RAM, and 2 SSD as RAID 0.

Is it possible to do something like load the table into memory and then run the queries? For example, is it possible to insert a table into the MEMORY storage engine and run queries against that, or is that stupid/crazy/worthless?

UPDATE: With a bit more additional searching and reading, it looks like there is no need to use the MEMORY story engine because InnoDB can load the tables into memory.

I changed the following in my.cnf:

- increasing the innodb_buffer_pool_size to 16G
- adding innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT

This reduced a query that took several minutes to 38 seconds.

Also, compressing the tables appears to help, and adding the following to my.cnf:

- innodb_file_per_table=1
- innodb_file_format=Barracuda

This reduced the query time to 31 seconds.

I'm still open to additional advice.